# Dynamically adjust UILabel x-value based on UIPicker location?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` that stretches to leading view and trailing view in `autolayout` in `storyboards`.

I would like to add a `UILabel` next to each section of the `UIPickerView` that stay a constant `10 px` away from the picker section.

Right now I am attempting to do so programmatically like so:

```
    var hourXVal = pickerWidth - 330.0
    var minXVal = pickerWidth - 190.0
    var secXVal = pickerWidth - 50.0

    if(self.view.frame.width == 320)
    {
        hourXVal = pickerWidth - 250.0
        minXVal = pickerWidth - 140.0
        secXVal = pickerWidth - 35.0
    }

    else if(self.view.frame.width == 414)
    {
        hourXVal = pickerWidth - 330.0
        minXVal = pickerWidth - 190.0
        secXVal = pickerWidth - 50.0
    }
    let hourLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:hourXVal, y:88, width: 100, height:40))
    let minuteLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:minXVal, y:88, width: 100, height:40))
    let secondLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:secXVal, y:88, width: 100, height:40))

    hourLabel.text = "Hours"
    minuteLabel.text = "Minutes"
    secondLabel.text = "Sec"

    self.timePickerView.addSubview(hourLabel)
    self.timePickerView.addSubview(minuteLabel)
    self.timePickerView.addSubview(secondLabel)
```

However, the `self.view.frame.width` reports the same width for an `iPhone SE` and `iPhone 6`even though for the 6 UI appears as so (Whereas it looks fine on the SE and 5):

[image]

Is there a better way to do this? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is probably happening is the when you call `self.view.frame.width` the correct view width has not yet been calculated. It could have the correct width for the iPhone 5/SE if that was used in Interface Builder. This can happen if you are calling code that needs the width in `-viewDidLoad` since the view is loaded, but its final size hasn't been calculated. Since you're working with frames, try setting it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.